How can I avoid the parameter pollution for passing context through execution flow?
I have a piece of context information which I need to make available throughout the execution of an Azure Function:
Function(context) -> Service(context) -> Repository(context) -> ApiClient(context) -> ...

public record TraceContext(
    Guid TraceId,
    string Domain = ""
);

Each layer may or may not need this information, therefore I do not like having to add this parameter to methods from the beginning to the end.
Moreover, any of the layers might update the context, this change should only propagate to the current layer and its children, without affecting instance in the parent layer.
I thought AsyncLocal<T> might be an option, though it is relatively new to me. I currently have an implementation similar to this.
TraceContextAccessor.cs
public class TraceContextAccessor
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<TraceContext> Current = new();

    public virtual TraceContext TraceContext
    {
        get => Current.Value ?? new TraceContext(Guid.Empty);
        set => Current.Value = value;
    }

    public TraceContextScope CreateScope(TraceContext traceContext)
    {
        return new TraceContextScope(this, traceContext);
    }
}

TraceContextScope.cs
public class TraceContextScope : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TraceContextAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly TraceContext _originalTraceContext;

    private bool _disposed;

    public TraceContextScope(TraceContextAccessor accessor, TraceContext newTraceContext)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;

        // Take a snapshot of the original value
        _originalTraceContext = accessor.TraceContext;

        // Set the new value
        SetTraceContext(newTraceContext);
    }

    private void SetTraceContext(TraceContext traceContext)
    {
        _accessor.TraceContext = traceContext;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            // Restore the original value
            SetTraceContext(_originalTraceContext);

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

TraceLogger.cs
public class TraceLogger(TraceContextAccessor traceContextAccessor)
{
    private readonly TraceContextAccessor _traceContextAccessor = traceContextAccessor;

    public Task LogMessage(string message)
    {
        var context = _traceContextAccessor.TraceContext;

        Console.WriteLine($"{message} - [{context.TraceId}].[{context.Domain}]");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public string BuildDomain(params string[] segments) => string.Join("_", segments);
}

Program.cs
services.AddSingleton<TraceContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<TraceLogger>();
services.AddScoped<DemoService>();

DemoFunction.cs
public class DemoFunction(
    DemoService demoService,
    TraceContextAccessor traceContextAccessor,
    TraceLogger traceLogger)
{
    private readonly DemoService _demoService = demoService;
    private readonly TraceContextAccessor _traceContextAccessor = traceContextAccessor;
    private readonly TraceLogger _traceLogger = traceLogger;

    [Function(nameof(DemoFunction))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        var initialContext = new TraceContext(TraceId: Guid.NewGuid(), Domain: "Demo");

        using (_traceContextAccessor.CreateScope(initialContext))
        {
            await _traceLogger.LogMessage($"{nameof(DemoFunction)} executing {nameof(Run)}.");
            await _demoService.Process();
            await _traceLogger.LogMessage($"{nameof(DemoFunction)} executed {nameof(Run)}.");
        }

        return new OkResult();
    }
}

public class DemoService(
    TraceLogger traceLogger,
    TraceContextAccessor traceContextAccessor)
{
    private readonly TraceLogger _traceLogger = traceLogger;
    private readonly TraceContextAccessor _traceContextAccessor = traceContextAccessor;

    public async Task Process()
    {
        // Log using the parent TraceContext
        await _traceLogger.LogMessage($"{nameof(DemoService)} executing {nameof(Process)}.");

        foreach (var country in new[] { "UK", "DE" })
        {
            // Create a new TraceContext
            var tcCurrent = _traceContextAccessor.TraceContext;
            var tcNew = tcCurrent with
            {
                Domain = _traceLogger.BuildDomain(tcCurrent.Domain, country)
            };

            // Switch to the the new TraceContext
            using (_traceContextAccessor.CreateScope(tcNew))
            {
                await _traceLogger.LogMessage($"{nameof(DemoService)} executing {nameof(Process)} for {country}.");

                var entities = await GetEntitiesByCountry(country);

                foreach (var entity in entities)
                {
                    await ProcessEntity(entity);
                }

                await _traceLogger.LogMessage($"{nameof(DemoService)} executed {nameof(Process)}  for {country}.");
            }
        }

        // Log using the parent TraceContext which should not have been modified by the loop
        await _traceLogger.LogMessage($"{nameof(DemoService)} executed {nameof(Process)}.");
    }

    public async Task ProcessEntity(string entity)
    {
        // Create a new TraceContext
        var tcCurrent = _traceContextAccessor.TraceContext;
        var tcNew = tcCurrent with
        {
            Domain = _traceLogger.BuildDomain(tcCurrent.Domain, entity)
        };

        // Switch to the the new TraceContext
        using (_traceContextAccessor.CreateScope(tcNew))
        {
            await _traceLogger.LogMessage($"{nameof(DemoService)} executing {nameof(ProcessEntity)}");
            // Process entity
        }
    }

    public async Task<string[]> GetEntitiesByCountry(string countryCode)
    {
        await _traceLogger.LogMessage($"{nameof(DemoService)} executing {nameof(GetEntitiesByCountry)}");
        // Call API with the HTTP headers from _traceContextAccessor.TraceContext

        return ["Entity01", "Entity02"];
    }
}

This provides the intended behavior:

Methods can create an instance of the TraceContext and make it available to the child scopes.
Child scopes can access to the current log metadata using Dependency Injection, they can also create a new context without affecting the one in the parent scope.
The context is attached to the async execution context and is not shared between different executions of the function/action.

At this point I am wondering:

Do you see any problems with this implementation?
Can this be achieved in a simpler way?


any of the layers might update the context - in your examples you don't really do that. Are you going to change the TraceContext in any way?

Yes the TraceContextAccessor has a way to set it but here I do it in the SetTraceContext method while creating a new scope with a using statement. Within that scope the new context is effective and outside the one from the parent.

I meant would you ever need to change the contents of a TraceContext object during the duration of the operation? It doesn't seem like it

Ah, no TraceContext itself is immutable. I create a new instance wherever I want to make a new version of it, then I want that version to be "current" for the child scopes further in the execution. See the tcCurrent with { ... } usages in DemoService
